# How to write json object into excel sheet using protractor api

Tags: excel, jasmine, protractor

How to write json object into excel sheet using protractor/jasmine api.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by doing this?

Comment: I want to write UI data present on application to json object and then to write that data into excel sheet

Answer (score 0):

You may use json2xls nodejs module for this purpose but you don't require protractor or jasmine for this conversion.

Comment: I have used json2xls but their i am not able to find out where to give sheet name(i.e sheet tab in excel sheet), in which i want to perform my data writing in excel sheet.

Comment: Please share you code on the forum so that community can help you otherwise it is very difficult for anyone to understand your problem.

Comment: var json2xls = require('json2xls');
gulp.task('abc', function() {
    var json = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('../xyz.json', 'utf8'));
    var xls = json2xls(json);
    fs.writeFileSync('../xyz.xlsx', xls,'binary', function (err) {
        if (err) {
            response.send("failed to save json object to excel sheet");
          } else {
            response.send("json object is saved to excel sheet");
          }});
});
but i want to write into sheet3 in "xyz.xlsx". So how to pass sheet name in above gulp task.by default it is writing in sheet1 of "xyz.xlsx".

Comment: Please @vishal have a look into code and help that how to pass sheet name